# PDF.js render pdf with scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc, pdf

I use mozilla pdf.js. I have a code:

```
<canvas id="the-canvas"/>
function displayDocument(){
        PDFJS.getDocument(numberOdDocument[attachment]).then(function (pdfDoc_) {
            pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
            renderPage(pageNum);
          });
    }
function renderPage(num) {
        pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {
          var viewport = page.getViewport(scale, rotate);
          canvas.height = '900';
          canvas.width = '500';

          var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: ctx,
            viewport: viewport
          };
          var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);

          renderTask.promise.then(function () {
            pageRendering = false;
            if (pageNumPending !== null) {
              renderPage(pageNumPending);
              pageNumPending = null;
            }
          });
        });
    }
```

Now i see only one page in canvas tag, but I want add scrollbar to my canvvas, and I want change page with scroll. How can I do that?

Comment: Looking for the same thing...

Answer (score 12):

**Allow scroll**

First, create a parent div to encapsulate the canvas element :

```
<div>
 <canvas id="the-canvas"/>
</div>
```

Then, set a fixed size with a vertical scroll

```
<div style="width:650px;height:600px;overflow-y:scroll;">...</div>
```

Finally, you can set the scale you want using the variable "scale" but keep these original lines :

```
function renderPage(num) {
 pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {
  var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
  canvas.height = viewport.height;
  canvas.width = viewport.width;
  ...
```

**Render all pages**

Keep in mind, that render a lot of pages will take a bit of time but here is how to do it.

Idea : you need to render each page in a separate canvas element.

First, create dynamically the canvas element with a specific id during render :

```
<div id="pdf-viewer"></div>
...
function renderPage(num) {
 pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {
  var canvasId = 'pdf-viewer-' + num;
  $('#pdf-viewer').append($('<canvas/>', {'id': canvasId}));
  var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
  ...
```

Finally, call renderPage() for each page

```
function renderAllPages() {
 for (var i = 1; i <= pdfDoc.numPages; i++) {
  renderPage(i);
 }
}
```